# Using the same function twice in a query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2005, query-optimization

In SQL Server 2005, when I write a query like

```
SELECT m.*, a.price p1, b.price p2
FROM mytable m
LEFT JOIN products_table_1 a
ON my_hash_function(m.name) = a.hash
LEFT JOIN products_table_2 b
ON my_hash_function(m.name) = b.hash
```

is `my_hash_function(m.name)` calculated twice or just once? If twice, how can I use a variable to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution plan shows that it indeed gets executed twice. But this holds only if the function is not **deterministic**. In order for a function to be deterministic, it must be defined `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option, and all the functions it calls must be deterministic as well. After I defined the hash function as deterministic, the plan has changed. Now it gets executed only once!

However, if you don't want to bother with that stuff, *momobo*'s solution works just as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
select  mm.*, a.price p1, b.price p2 from   
    (SELECT m.*, my_hash_function(m.name) as name
    FROM mytable m) mm
    LEFT JOIN products_table_1 a
    ON mm.name = a.hash
    LEFT JOIN products_table_2 b
    ON mm.name = b.hash
```

Comment: Oh, I get the idea. Thanks! Do you know whether it would be executed twice otherwise or not?

Comment: I think it depends on the optimizer reasoning. I don't know but I suppose that it wouldn't.